# Absolute Galois group and continuous homomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

Let $G=\mathrm{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ be the absolute Galois group of a number field $K$.

I have some problem to understand that the homomoprhism

$$ \rho :G \longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_r(E)$$

$E$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$, is continuous if and only if for all $n$ there exist a finite extension $E_n/K$  such that $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar K/E_n) \mapsto \mathrm{id} \ \ (\mathrm{mod}\: \ell^n)$. And what about if I replace $E$ with $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It is not clear why after "if and only if" the symbol $\rho$ does not appear. What is $\rho$? Is it an arbitrary homomorphism, or is it a specific one?

Comment: You are right, it is an arbitrary homomorphism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of the issue is that your question doesn't make sense literally, unless you are committing an identification which, if you understood, would probably make your question moot.

In particular, what does it mean to reduce a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_r(E)$ modulo $\ell^n$? The thing you are secretly assuming, which is fine, is that by continuity (and compactness of $G$) $\rho$ stabilizes a $\mathcal{O}_E$-lattice in $E^r$. Thus, up to changing basis, we may as well assume that we are given $\rho$ as a continuous morphism $G\to\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E)$. But, $\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E)$ is profinite. In particular:

$$\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E)=\varprojlim \mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E/\pi^n)$$

where $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $E$. So, we see that $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E)$ is continuous with the $\pi$-adic topology if and only if the maps $\rho_n:G\to\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E/\pi^n)$ are continuous with the discrete topology for all $n$.

But, by definition this means that $\ker\rho_n$ is open. Thus, we are asking that for all $n$ there is a finite extension $E_n$ of $K$ such that

$$\rho_n(G_{E_n})=\{I_r\}\subseteq\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E/\pi^n)$$

Now, this answers your question with $\mod \ell^n$ replaced with $\mod \pi^n$. But, since $E/\mathbb{Q}_\ell$, so in particular $\mathcal{O}_E\supseteq\mathbb{Z}_\ell$, it's not hard to see how to finish the argument (Hint: consider the canonical map $\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E/\ell^n)\to\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathcal{O}_E/\pi^n)$)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I have a $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$-module of rank $r$ or a $\mathbb{Z}/\ell\mathbb{Z}$ module of dimension $r$ equipped with a continuous action of $G$, then $\rho$ identify such action if we replace $E$ with the suitable structure. So wich conditions $\rho$ need to satisfy to be a continuous homomorphism?

Comment: @user262440 I mean, it's the exact thing. In fact, what I proved above is the condition for the $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ case to be continuous (and reduced to that for $E$) and in the proof of the $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ case I used to $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}$ case!